# Generating a random number with CDF $P(X \leq c) = 1-1/c$ in the interval $(1, + \infty)$. using uniform distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, density-function, random-generation

I have a uniform number generator in ($0, 1).$ I want to generate a random number with CDF $P(X \leq c) = 1-1/c$ in the interval $(1, + \infty)$. I know I should apply the inverse of my function to the random variable sampled from the uniform distribution. Bit I don't know how to go about 'shifting' the domain to $(1, + \infty)$. I would appreciate if someone help my find the formula (steps to do this).

Comment: Running $\text{uniform}(0, 1)$ RVs through the inverse of $F(x) = 1 - 1/x$ will give you numbers in $(1, \infty)$

Comment: You don't need to do *anything* about the domain, because correct computation of the inverse will automatically return a value in $(1,\infty).$  Finding the formula means solving the equation $u=1-1/c$ for $c$ when $u$ is in the interval $(0,1).$  If you need help with that, [math.se] is a good place to ask.

Comment: @Glen_b you are correct. i fixed it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mostly addressed in the comments, but I'm going to write a more formal answer.

The whole point of the probability integral transform (a more formal way of saying *"inverse of my function to the random variable sampled from the uniform distribution"*) is that the "shifting" from $(0,1) \to (1, \infty)$ is done automatically. In essence, if we can invert

$$F(x) = P(x \leq X) = 1 - \frac{1}{x}$$

then we are done (provided we have a $\text{uniform}(0, 1)$ generator, such as `runif()` in `R`).

Now let's invert $F(x)$. Let $y = 1 - \frac{1}{x}$. It then follows that $\frac{1}{x} = 1 - y$ and thus $x = \frac{1}{1 - y}$ (we need $y \neq 1$ for this step to be valid, this is indeed true). That is $F^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{1 - x}$.

Now to generate values which are distributed according to $F(x)$, we simply generate $\text{uniform}(0,1)$ random variates, and run them through $F^{-1}(x)$.

```
set.seed(1)

f_inv = function(x) {
  1 / (1 - x)
}

n = 10^5

x = runif(n)

y = f_inv(x)

summary(y)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
    1.000     1.330     2.000     9.627     4.014 18896.753
```

Comment: Of course, you can save yourself a tiny bit of computation by noting that the dist'n of `x` and `1-x` are the same, and just returning `1/x`.

Comment: @jbowman good point(+1)! However, I guess my approach is much clearer to someone who is unfamiliar with the method

Comment: Oh sure, for expositional purposes your approach is better.  I'm making a trivial (at best) point.